# nested for loops in Python involving 2 files

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 2 files: one (ranges.txt) with rows that contain 2 tab-delimited integers, and a second (values.txt) with tab-delimited values, the first of which is an integer. The integers in ranges.txt represent the start and end points for a range, and for each of these ranges I want to ask how many of the integers in values.txt fall in this range. As a starting point, I have written this bit of code:

```
RangesFile = open('ranges.txt', 'r')
ValuesFile = open('values.txt', 'r')
for Line in RangesFile:
    RangesFile.next()
    print Line
    Line = Line.strip('\n')
    RangeValues = Line.split('\t')
    Start = int(RangeValues[0])
    End = int(RangeValues[1])
    print Start
    print End
    for Line in ValuesFile:
        Line = Line.strip('\n')
        ElementList = Line.split('\t')
        SNP = int(ElementList[0])
        print SNP
        print 'yes' if Start <= SNP <= End else 'no'        

RangesFile.close()
ValuesFile.close()
```

I get the following output for test files with 2 ranges and 2 integers:

```
1867    4663

1867
4663
1923
yes
10384150
no
15274293    15275591

15274293
15275591
17486938    17490453
```

The nested loop does not seem to run after the first iteration. What have I done wrong?
(I know my code is overly long, but I'm trying to keep things simple as an absolute beginner.)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fix your indentation, this snippet is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Agree with Cat Plus Plus -- can't tell if your indentation is a formatting error here or the part of the source of your problems ...

Comment: Sorry, it now looks like my code - I haven't quite figured out the formatting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the second `for` loop reads the whole `ValuesFile`. after its execution, the file pointer is at the end of the file, and there is no more values to be read from it.

you should reset the `ValuesFile` file pointer before starting the second `for` loop to start reading `ValuesFile` from the beginning again.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Do I have to reopen ValuesFile every time I go through the loop, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: there are more efficient ways, like calling `ValuesFile.seek(0)`. see [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106820/re-open-files-in-python) for more details.

Comment: Even better would be to read each file only once, and use a data structure in memory to perform the work.

Comment: i would bet that `ValuesFile` may grow very big. but reading `RangesFile` into a list of tuples and going through the values only once would be a great improvement. anyway, let the beginners start at the beginning...