# I am trying to find and replace the values in the text file

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a text file containing values (e.g.0.2803739 0.280314). I would like to replace the values in the text file in such a way that highest value will be replaced by lowest value and so on. e.g. If text file contains  values from 1 to 10 then value 10 should be replaced by value 1, value 9 should be replaced by 2, value 8 should be replaced by 3 and so on. In the following script the 3rd "for loop" is getting ignored.

```
import fileinput

text_file = r"E:\Jagu\test123.txt"
f1 = open(text_file, 'r')

unique_v = set(f1.read().split())
a = list(unique_v)

new_list1= list(a)
new_list1.sort(reverse = True )

new_list2 = new_list1
new_list2.sort(reverse = False )

l = 0
m = len (new_list2)
m = m-1

f2 = open(text_file + ".tmp", 'w')

for j in new_list1: 
    c = new_list1 [l]
    l = l + 1
    for k in new_list2:
        d = new_list2[m]
        m = m - 1
        for line in f1:
            f2.write(line.replace(c,d))
            print "replaced : " + str(c)  + " with : " + str(d)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Hope the explanation is helpful to understand my issue. I am a beginner in Python programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1:

```
new_list2 = new_list1
```

This will make `new_list2` and `new_list1` point to same list. You need

```
new_list2 = list(a)
```

or

```
new_list2 = new_list[:]
```

Issue 2:

You cannot do

```
for line in f1:
```

after you have `read()` from `f1`.

Do

```
f1.seek(0)
l = f1.readlines()
for line in f1:
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've called f1.read() you're at the end of the file, so call f1.seek(0) so you can read it again in the last for loop.

See [Re-open files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106820/re-open-files-in-python) for more information.