# Weird loop in a CSV file parser

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a Python that is going to read every **x** seconds a CSV file.

What I do is:

Open the file, read the info as CSV, loop every entry

This is done in this Python file:

```
import csv
import time
import datetime


CSV_PLAN = "./XoceKochPlan.csv"
chargePlanFile = open(CSV_PLAN, 'rt')

def loopMe():
    try:
        for eachRow in reader:
            print (eachRow)
    except Exception, ex:
        print ("Error processFileing the Thread" + str(ex))


print ("opening file " + str(CSV_PLAN))
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H %M %S %Z %Y")
print ("Now " + str(now))
reader = csv.reader(chargePlanFile)

loopMe()
```

The output is so far so good.

But if I do:

```
loopMe()
time.sleep(10)
loopMe()
```

then the file is only printed once!

The question is **Why?**

What am I missing? What is getting internally consumed, or is the reader just empty after the first loop?

Comment: Before your reader is still at the end of the file.

Comment: You should reassign : `reader = csv.reader(chargePlanFile)`

Comment: @iFlo: nope, after re-reading the file still one loop!

Comment: Here is existing topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106820/re-open-files-in-python

Answer (score 1):

In python the file io handler has an internal pointer. After reading the file it will be at the end of the csv file.  Ensure you call the `chargePlanFile.close()` method and reopen the file before calling the `loopme()` function. Or use the `chargePlanFile.seek(0)` to reset the position of the internal pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the second loop, your reader is already at the last line. You should reassign the reader. You should do it inside your `loopMe` function at the beginning.

```
def loopMe():
    reader = csv.reader(chargePlanFile)
    try:
        for eachRow in reader:
            print (eachRow)
    except Exception, ex:
        print ("Error processFileing the Thread" + str(ex))
```

If you would keep the same code, just add `reader.seek(0)` in the first line of `loopMe`