# error when itertating twice on python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem running the python code below on Jupyter-notebook. 
It's okay when I iterate once, but if I change the code to iterate twice, I get errors, why is that?

this is the right answer when I iterate once.
   [image: picture 1:]

this is the error when I iterate twice
   [image: picture 2 :]

```
import csv
csvfile = open("sales_rank.csv")
reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
header=next(reader)

category={}
rank={}

for row in reader:
    category.setdefault(row[1],[]).append(row[4]) 

for each in reader:
    rank.setdefault(row[3],[]).append(row[0])
```

Comment: Output and errors should be pasted here, not as images.

Comment: You need to rewind to the beginning of the file before the second loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-open files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106820/re-open-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time you do `for <variable> in reader:`, `csvfile` is already at the end of the file, so there's nothing left to read. You need to go back to the beginning of the file.

```
import csv
csvfile = open("sales_rank.csv")
reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
header=next(reader)

category={}
rank={}

for row in reader:
    category.setdefault(row[1],[]).append(row[4]) 

csvfile.seek(0)

for each in reader:
    rank.setdefault(row[3],[]).append(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`reader` is an iterator, and your first for loop runs until the iterator is finished. So when you get to the second loop, there's nothing left to iterate over. In between the loops, you need to reset the iterator. You can try `reader.seek(0)` to reset its position, I'm not sure if that works with a `csv.reader`. If that doesn't work, you can reset it by just calling `reader = csv.reader(csvfile)` again.

Comment: it worked with csvfile.seek(0)  thanks for your help!