# Function does not call after 1 iteration

Tags: python, csv, file

I am creating a menu based program that reads and writes to a csv for schoolwork.

```py
import csv
with open(r"C:/Users/sony/Desktop/CS/csv.csv","r+",newline='') as f:
    def read():
        csv_r = csv.reader(f)
        for line in csv_r:
            for i in range(len(line)):
                print(line[i],' ',end='')
            print()
    def write():
        csv_w=csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        csv_w.writerow([input("Enter Product Name"),input("Enter Price"),input("Enter Quantity")])
    while True:
        print("1.Read")
        print("2.Write")
        function=int(input("Enter Choice of Function"))
        if function==1:
            read()
        elif function==2:
            write()
        else:
            break
```

The problem is that after first iteration of the loop, if you call the read function , it wont print it to the console. What should I do to fix this? I could not find similar questions as well.

Comment: It works for first iteration tho. and write function works for every iteration

Comment: Have a think about the code structure and decide if your function (`def`) declarations would be better placed elsewhere.

Comment: I tried placing them outside the (with open ) under the imports . Did not do anything.Still the problem exists

Comment: You’re on the right track, keep going.  Hint: Think about the iteration and what might need to be passed into the read/write functions.  They might need to be generalised.

Comment: I don't see any recursion here; please [edit] to either clarify how it's relevant, or to remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: They need access to `f`, which you either pass as parameter or, like above, use the feature of binding them in a closure, @S3DEV.

Comment: This should first be reduced to a [mcve]. Still, the problem is reading and writing to the same file, which doesn't work the way you expect it to. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that after the first time you read the file, the position in the file stays at the end. To fix this, you can reopen your file each time you need to access it, this will allow you to read the contents of the file as many times as needed.

You may also want to consider re-arranging your code a bit—specifically move your function definitions outside of the main loop.

Here's an example:

```py
import csv


def read():
    with open("C:/Users/sony/Desktop/CS/csv.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
        csv_r = csv.reader(f)
        for line in csv_r:
            for i in range(len(line)):
                print(line[i], " ", end="")
            print()


def write():
    with open("C:/Users/sony/Desktop/CS/csv.csv", "a+", newline="") as f:
        csv_w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
        csv_w.writerow([
            input("Enter Product Name"),
            input("Enter Price"),
            input("Enter Quantity"),
        ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print("1.Read")
        print("2.Write")
        function = int(input("Enter Choice of Function"))
        if function == 1:
            read()
        elif function == 2:
            write()
        else:
            break
```

Alternatively, you can call `f.seek(0)` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106820/re-open-files-in-python)) before reading to move back to the beginning of the file. However, the approach I've provided here as an example is easier to extend to working with different or multiple files.